# Is it possible to open an attachment in an iframe in confluence?

Tags: iframe, attachment, confluence

In confluence I have links to attachments like so:

```
<ac:link><ri:attachment ri:filename="attachmentFile" /><ac:plain-text-link-body><![CDATA[Link to attachment File]]></ac:plain-text-link-body></ac:link>
```

I also found that iframes can be put into confluence like so:

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="html" ac:schema-version="1"><ac:parameter ac:name="atlassian-macro-output-type">INLINE</ac:parameter><ac:plain-text-body><![CDATA[<iframe src="http://www.atlassian.com/" noborder="0" width="830" height="800" scrolling="yes" seamless></iframe>]]></ac:plain-text-body></ac:structured-macro>
```

Now I want somehow to combine the two. I want to have a link to the attachment that opens the attachment in an iframe. Is this possible? I haven't found any documentation on it so I'm hoping someone has achieved it

Thx

A

Answer (score 1):

Try using the attachment full address. Go the attachments page, and click on your attachment, that URL is the full address. The following works for an attachment with name "img_welcome.png" that belongs to the page 98334:

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="html"><ac:plain-text-body><![CDATA[<iframe src="http://YOURDOMAIN/download/attachments/98334/img_welcome.png?api=v2" noborder="0" width="830" height="800" scrolling="yes" seamless></iframe>]]></ac:plain-text-body></ac:structured-macro>
```

Not sure what do you want to get, but [Comala Share It](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.keinoby.confluence.plugins.share-attachments/server/overview) creates unique public links that can be used to embed pages and attachments outside your Confluence instance. Check [this out](https://wiki.comalatech.com/display/SI/How+to+Embed+a+Shared+Page)!

Disclaimer, I work in Comalatech, the company behind that add-on.

Regards,
Gorka

Comment: that opens the attachment in an iframe on the current page. what I wanted in a link that opens the attachment in an iframe in a popup